# In ASP.NET Core Tag Helper public Attribute not working as expected

Tags: razor, asp.net-core

I've copied the demo from the ASP.NET core for the email tag helper.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/authoring

When I create a tag on my view page that looks like this:

```
<div>
  <Email MailTo="abc"></Email>
</div>
```

I expect that the public property MailTo will be set but it is not (when I debug, it shows as null).  However when I get the output attribute from the TagHelperOutput as follows:

```
var mailToWorks = output.Attributes["MailTo"].Value.ToString();
```

mailToWorks gets "abc" as I would expect but the public poperty MailTo is not set.  My Tag Helper source is below.

```
    [HtmlTargetElement("Email")]
    public class EmailTagHelper : TagHelper
    {
        private const string EmailDomain = "contoso.com";

        // Can be passed via <email mail-to="..." />. 
        // Pascal case gets translated into lower-kebab-case.
        public string MailTo { get; set; }

        public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
        {
            var mailToWorks = output.Attributes["MailTo"].Value.ToString();

            output.TagName = "a";    // Replaces <email> with <a> tag

            var address = MailTo + "@" + EmailDomain;
            output.Attributes.SetAttribute("href", "mailto:" + address);
            output.Content.SetContent(address);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think it says you should have this: <email mail-to="abc"></email>

Comment: Thanks @SerifEmek  You are correct, that solves the problem.  What is odd is that intelisense suggests the "MailTo" in purple. it also likes mail-to once I type it out. Does that make sense?

Comment: You are wellcome. No, it does'nt. Actually, I am not familiar with the usage. Just learned from your link.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to turn off the translation into lower-kebab-case, you can use the `HtmlAttributeNameAttribute`.

```
// matches <email MailTo="..." />
[HtmlAttributeName(nameof(MailTo))]
public string MailTo { get; set; }
```